# In AWS Stepfunctions, when Catch an error, how identify which state threw the error? (Pass a string literal plus the current state name)

Tags: aws-step-functions

In the simplified AWS Step Function below, if there is an error thrown by *any* of the three states `foo1`, `foo2`, or `foo3`, the state `fooerr` will Catch the error.

My question is, how to inform `fooerr` ***which*** of the states it is catching the error from?

(In this example all four foo* states invoke a lambda, so I want to pass the state name "foo2" and a string literal such as "foo2_literal" to `fooerr` lambda if `foo2` has an error.)

[image: step function]

For example, if state `foo2` is defined:

```
"foo2": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:11111111111:function:foo2:$LATEST",
        "Payload": {
          "Input.$": "$"
        }
      },
      "Next": "foo3",
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "Next": "fooerr"
        }
      ]
    },
```

I cannot find any examples of syntax in Catch for inserting an identifier string that will get passed to `fooerr`.

Similarly, I do not see how/where **name** of the state *causing* the error is passed to the state (fooerr) that *catches* the error.

In this example, I'd like `foo2` to "send" the identifiers "foo2" and "foo2_literal_string" to `foorerr` if an error occurs in `foo2`.

Comment: When the catcher receives the error, it gets the error message and the error type. Wrap your functions in try/except and throw your own custom wrapped exceptions. Then in the catcher, check the error type to route your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for but I can think of these 3 alternatives:

1. You can use different `ResultPath` in `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3`, for example for `foo1` use this:

```
"Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "ResultPath": "$.foo1-error",
          "Next": "fooerr"
        }
      ]
```

This way in `fooerr` you can use a chioce state and check if `foo1-error` exist or not.

2. create separate error catcher for each of those states (`foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3`).
   `foo1` -catch-> `fooerr1`

`foo2` -catch-> `fooerr2`

`foo2` -catch-> `fooerr3`

3. instead of using `fooerr` as `Next` step in catch block, use another step in between to add the data you need for each of them. So create something like this:

`foo1` -catch-> `foo1-with-error-data` -> `fooerr`

`foo2` -catch-> `foo2-with-error-data` -> `fooerr`

`foo2` -catch-> `foo2-with-error-data` -> `fooerr`

Comment: The actual statemachine is much larger, so I'm prefer not to have to customize each 'catch', and certainly hope to avoid separate error handlers, but approach #1 might work OK, thank you! I'm hoping a simpler approach might arise such as some way for foorerr to "see" who caught and sent the error, but if not this will work.